# Subtract and paste answer in subsequent rows until the value changes again

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 columns of data - B10:E(LastRow).

Coulmn 1 = Dates - Not needed

Coulmn 2 = Money - Not Needed

Coulmn 3 = Segments Sold - Needed

Column 4 = Segments Left - Needed

I am struggling to write the code for Column 4.

I have a fixed value of segments called from Cells(4, 3), which is 100 in this case, to start the if statement.

I know my below code is incorrect.

```
For k = 10 To LR1
    If ws2.Cells(k, "D") = 0 Then
        ws2.Cells(k, "E") = 100
    ElseIf ws2.Cells(k, "D") > 0 Then
        ws2.Cells(k, "E") = ws2.Cells(4, 3) - ws2.Cells(k, "D")
    End If
Next k
```

Basically I want Cells 10: to the first value that is > 0 to equal 100.

Then I want the cells 11th, from the first value greater than 0, we shall say 3, to be 97, until the next value greater than 0, say 7, thus it will equals 90 and so on for the rest of the column.

I hope this is clear enough. I have attached an image, left one is what I currently get, right one is what I would like to achieve.

**Left** - What I get with the if function // **Right** - What I want to achieve

[image]

Comment: Why don't just do upper cell minus left cell? I did manually 100 into `E16` and then my formula in `E17` is `=E16-D17` and drag down. This returns exactly your expected output

Comment: Because sometimes I Like to extremely overcomplicate matters :) Thank you for your moment of clarity, it is much appreciated! 

I put that into my Macro instead.